# How to fetch a sys_refcursor to an asociative array table in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, procedure

Having this definitions:

```
TYPE type_record1 IS RECORD(
id NUMBER,
value NUMBER
);

v_count NUMBER;

TYPE tp_arr_record IS TABLE OF type_record1 INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

v_t_arr_record   tp_arr_record;

v_results sys_refcursor;
```

And:

```
v_results := f_execute_cursor(id_process);
```

How I can fetch this weak cursor (v_results) using an asociative array like this form:

```
FOR idx IN v_results 
    LOOP
      v_count   :=  v_count + 1;
      v_t_arr_record(v_count).id      :=  idx.id;
      v_t_arr_record(v_count).value   :=  idx.value;
    END LOOP;
```

In other words, how can fetch from a sys_refcursor into an asociative array without using a record because I need to get the data set from the cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using almost the same code as I used when answering another one of your other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296617/how-to-get-data-from-a-pl-sql-function-if-a-parameter-have-more-than-one-value-i/56299147#56299147) this takes the Products that are returned by your Function and stores the values into a collection.

Please let me know if you are needing clarification or if you have other questions regarding my answer here.

```
DECLARE

  /* Store Ref Cursor returned by f_process_data() Function */
  v_result_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;

  /* Declare Record so we can store the data FETCHed from the Cursor */
  rec_product       products%ROWTYPE;

  /* Declare Type based off of products table */
  TYPE  t_products  IS TABLE OF products%ROWTYPE;

  /* Declare Table based off of Type t_products and initialize it. */
  tab_products      t_products   :=    t_products();

  /* Declare a couple Product Variables for Proof of Concept */
  v_sausage         NUMBER;
  v_ham             NUMBER;

  /* Store output */
  n_id              NUMBER;
  v_id_product      VARCHAR2(100);

  /* Declare Type of TABLE NUMBER */
  TYPE  nt_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

  /* Create Array/Table/Collection of type nt_type to store product ids */
  nt_product_ids    nt_type;

  /* Returns a Ref Cursor based on the product_id used as Input to this function */
  FUNCTION f_process_data(p_id_process IN NUMBER, p_id_product IN NUMBER)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  AS
    /* Declare Ref Cursor that will be Returned */
    rc_result_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;    

  BEGIN 
    /* Open Ref Cursor based on Product ID parameter */
    OPEN rc_result_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM products WHERE item_id = p_id_product;

    RETURN rc_result_cursor;

  END f_process_data
  ;

BEGIN

  /* Set Product Variables to IDs */
  v_sausage       := 2003;
  v_ham           := 2007;

  /* Store product ids into a Number Table so we can Loop thru it */
  nt_product_ids  :=  nt_type (v_sausage,v_ham);

  FOR r IN nt_product_ids.FIRST .. nt_product_ids.LAST
  LOOP
    /* Get Ref Cursor using SINGLE Product ID */
    v_result_cursor := f_process_data(1, nt_product_ids(r));

    LOOP

      FETCH v_result_cursor INTO rec_product;

      n_id            :=  rec_product.item_id;
      v_id_product    :=  rec_product.item;

      EXIT WHEN v_result_cursor%NOTFOUND;

      --dbms_output.put_line('Product_id: ' || n_id);
      --dbms_output.put_line('Product: ' || v_id_product); 

      /* Store data into Collection */
      tab_products.EXTEND(1);          
      /* Set the Row inside the tab_products Table at the newly extended Index to the record rec_product */
      tab_products(tab_products.COUNT)  :=  rec_product;

    END LOOP; /* Cursor Loop */

    /* Close Cursor */
    CLOSE v_result_cursor;

  END LOOP; /* Product IDs Loop */

dbms_output.put_line('Total Products in tab_products COllECTION: ' || tab_products.COUNT);

/* Now we can just loop thru our tab_products Collection */
For r IN tab_products.FIRST .. tab_products.LAST
LOOP

  dbms_output.put_line('Product: ' || tab_products(r).item_id ||' - ' || tab_products(r).item);

END LOOP;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS
  THEN CLOSE v_result_cursor;

END;
```

Comment: No clarifications, it's fine but I need to study this and apply in another project. Thanks.

Comment: @reymagnus This link to one of my own SO Posts may or may not help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855857/oracle-how-to-add-a-record-to-a-collection-of-the-same-type-multiset-union